# Are there any Android apps available or in development that emulate Dragon 32 computers?

Tags: android, emulator

I used to love playing the old retro games on my [Dragon 32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_32/64) many years ago until it finally stopped working. I now have a nexus 7 and have many emulators but have not found one for my beloved Dragon. Anyone know of any or if one is on development?

On Windows based computers I used an emulator called WinRoar, which was ported to the X-Box as XRoar. Both of these ports allowed the use of keyboard controls and joystick controllers.

They both opened tape and disk files and I believe that they also opened cartridge files.

I would like to know if anyone could port a version like the PC and XBox versions to run on Android Kit Kat OS on a 2012 Nexus 7 allowing touchscreen joystick and keyboard operations.

If the port could allow the use of Dragon 32 and 64 as well as Tandy CoCo machines that would be preferable.

Comment: Do to the fairly limited scope of this question it is marginally acceptable - but could be improved vastly; see this [meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) fir suggestions

Answer (score 3):

I need a little more time to work it out, and you need some sort of terminal emulator - (I have [this installed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en)) and some additional files to get it working properly (which , but there *is* [a port for xroar on android](http://www.6809.org.uk/xroar/#ports) - assuming you're willing to sideload.

I don't own a Dragon (so i can't legally download a rom to test - the software SEEMS to install and run to some degree on my android 4.2 phone), but the readme suggests you can load a .cas file amongst other things as you can see below

> Use the Android command line to load files into the emulator:
>
> $ am start -a android.intent.action.RUN \
>            -n uk.org.six809.xroar/.MainActivity \
>            -d filename.cas

Comment: Thanks for this Journeyman Geek. I have downloaded the Android apk files as you say. Followed the readme that is on the xroar site and got the Dragon 32 screen to appear which brought back some happy memories, but I am struggling to get the terminal emulator to run the games through the xroar emulator. I have tried Terminal IDE as well, but to no avail. Can anyone help with getting this to work?